# Question concerning sorting numbers by string/dealing with tiebreakers?

Tags: sorting, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am currently re-educating myself on Google sheets and I was wondering if there was a way to sort a set of numbers by string to deal with tiebreakers (i.e. a win/loss/tie record)

Using the SORT function, I was able to sort things correctly based on wins, but I want to be able to adjust it even further. Currently I have something like this...

- 3-0-0
- 1-4-0
- 1-3-0
- 1-2-0
- 1-1-0

when I want to have something like this, where the values with the lowest loss record goes on top instead...

- 3-0-0
- 1-1-0
- 1-2-0
- 1-3-0
- 1-4-0

Is there another function or a workaround possible to achieve something like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
=SORT(A1:A5,INDEX(SPLIT(A1:A5,"-"),,1),0,INDEX(SPLIT(A1:A5,"-"),,2),1)
```

- `SPLIT(A1:A5,"-")` by `-`
- `INDEX(SPLIT(A1:A5,"-"),,1)` get first column of the split array
- `INDEX(SPLIT(A1:A5,"-"),,2)` get second column
- `=SORT(A1:A5,col1,0,col2,1)` Sort A1:A5 in descending order based on column1 and ascending order based on column 2

Comment: Used it and it worked nicely. I had already experimented with the SPLIT formula, but I had a feeling there had to have been another formula to work with. Thank you!

Comment: Curious to ask how I could be able to get the right-most value with this formula? Could I use another SPLIT or a RIGHT in the SORT formula?

Comment: @MrWV `INDEX(SPLIT(A1:A5,"-"),,3)`

Answer (score 0):

While in "human language" something like `3-0-0` could be called "a set of numbers" in "spreadsheet language" it's a text value.

To be able to use the built-in sorting functions in Google Sheets, you should split the values into columns, and guess what, there is a built-in function for that:

1. Select the column
2. Click on Data > Split text to columns
3. Select custom separarator and set `-`

There are a more options, like using a formulas and scripts.

Sample formula

```
=ArrayFormula(QUERY(
{A1:A5,REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A5,"-(\d{1,})-")},
"select Col1 order by Col2",0)
)
```

The above formula use a regular expression to extract the numbers between `-`, then use QUERY to sorth the values in `A1:A5` in ascending order by using these values.

Comment: In this case, I went and used some formulas such as SORT and SORTN to find a workaround, but it usually results in the highest loss  value on the top (1-4-0, 1-3-0, 1-2-0, etc.) Are there any other formulas to look up and watch out for to get my desired result?